# Cannot Start Libre Office 5.2 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, libreoffice

I cannot start LibreOffice - every attempt results in the error message:

> The program cannot be started. A general error occurred while accessing your central configuration. ("component context fails to supply service com.sun.star.configuration.ReadWriteAccess of type com.sun.star.configuration.XReadWriteAccess")

I have tried both from shortcuts and directly on the soffice app file

I have a fresh install of LibreOffice.

I have tried resetting my user profile - but there isn't one!
Repair install doesn't work
Standard installer - no dev builds

Thanks

Comment: Libre Office 5.1 doesn't work either - error message -> The program cannot be started. A general error occurred while accessing your central configuration ("service not supplied")

Comment: Obviously no-one knows how to answer this question. What tools are available that I can use to collect more information and to help track down the answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to reinstall Windows 10 - now LibreOffice 5 works fine.

Answer (score -1):

This solution works for me:

[Libre office 5 problems and solutions](https://blog.softhints.com/libre-office-5-problems-and-solutions/)

> Repair LibreOffice in Windows
>
> - Menu **Start**
> - **Control Panel**
> - **Programs and Features**
> - Find LibreOffice and Right Click on it
> - Select **Repair** (Three options appear a. Uninstall b. Change c. Repair)
> - Wait for LibreOffice reconfiguration and **restart**.
> - Open LibreOffice after the restart.